# Best upgrade path?

Tags: migrations, 9, upgrading

One of my Drupal sites has been languishing on Drupal 5.

It has a lot of content, so I can't just start from scratch. I'm considering to finally upgrade it to Drupal 9.

What would be the best and easiest path to getting all caught up?

Should I make a clone of my most recent 5 on a development machine, then install each of the next version using its upgrade method?

Can I just install Drupal 9 over my ancient Drupal 5 site on the development machine, and hammer through all of the errors until I (hopefully) get them all sorted out?

Is there a much better way?

Comment: There's no such thing "best". It's up to you. I'd recommend to completely relaunch the site. And then use some batch form to hook into the ancient database and create new content and users from it. Maybe also look at https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_drupal_d5

Answer (score 1):

5 is so old I would treat it as "migrating from a generic website to Drupal 9."

I would try to approach this using the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module, which allows you to import content from one site into another.

There was no version of Feeds for Drupal 5 (started with 6), but you should be able to find some way to export the content with Views in 5 (perhaps to CSV?) and then you can import it with Feeds.

Feeds has great support for the "core" Drupal entities-- users, nodes, taxonomy terms.  But, I'm not sure about "forum posts"-- the forum module has been a bit neglected compared to other modules, so this may be a pain point (or it may magically work-- no need to be unnecessarily negative).  So if you do decide to go the Feeds route, I would test something relatively easy (users) and then test the forum posts next to evaluate the difficulty of the upgrade.

Comment: I am using the Advanced Forums module on v5 to handle the forums; the largest purpose of the site was it's forums. Is the v9 forums worth going though this upgrade? Or do ya think it might be better to try migrating over to something like a WordPress forum or a dedicated forum software instead?

Comment: If the site is mainly a forum, I would consider dedicated forum software. Advanced Forum port to D8 was abandoned: https://github.com/drupal-ukraine/advanced_forum/issues/2  There was a lot of work on socially oriented Drupal during the Drupal 7 era, but Drupal 8/9 is much more focused on big corporate sites than small community sites.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you do, you're going to have to do a lot of work. Going forward, Drupal has changed the way major upgrades are done so from now on instead of major efforts to go from D5 to D6 to D7 etc. there should be only a small amount of ongoing work necessary to keep your site up-to-date. But you have to get to at least D8 to take advantage of that ...

Using Migrate to go from Drupal 6 to Drupal 8/9 is pretty well documented, and the problems you will encounter are mostly known and also documented. But this Migrate process doesn't work for Drupal 5, so I suggest trying to update from D5 to D6 first. This is also a pretty simple process. See for example [Upgrading from Drupal 5.x to Drupal 6.x - Tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/340073)

How well this all works out will depend on a lot of things specific to your site, mostly whether the contributed modules you rely on have been ported to D6/D9 and whether they support Migrate for going from D6 to D9. Another problem is going to be your theme - theming has changed substantially between D5 and D9 so you might have to do a lot of work to get the look you want. You will not be able to keep the same look as you have now, but that's probably a good thing because D5 sites look really dated.

If your main goal is to preserve your content, then I think your chances of success are much better if you stay with Drupal than if you try to move to some other CMS / software because even though D9 is quite different from D5, the jump is less than the difference between Drupal and WordPress.